# Nodemailer HTML not working with sendgrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid and nodemailer trying to send an HTML email.
here is the code:

```
for(var i = 0;i<emails.length; i++){
    email.sendMail({
        from:'"Name" <noreply@domain.com>',
        to:emails[i],
        HTML:"<h1>hi</h1>",
        generateTextFromHTML:true,
        subject: "Blah"
    },function(err,res){
        if(err){console.log(err)};
        if(res){console.log(res.message)};
    })
}
```

let me know if you need anymore information let me know.
thanks,
ari

Comment: did you try sending just one email? Does it work without the loop? We need more information about your `email` and `emails` object / array

Comment: You need to give us the output of `err`, `res`, and `res.message` at minimum in order to debug.  Also, the setup would help too.

Comment: Have you tried the key 'html' instead of 'HTML', and have do you defined a nodemailer transport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Out this was an error with my usage of the sendgrid API.
sorry.